# google chrome extension: not throwing errors?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

When there's a problem in the content or background script, I do not get any error messages outputted in the console. Neither will it print anything to the console via console.log('msg'). except when I do alert() explicitly.

I am copying and pasting the javascript in the console manually to catch errors, but there must be a better way of debugging a chrome extension script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two consoles, one for your popup and one for the background pages. You're probably looking at the wrong one.

You can access the popup console by right clicking your extension's icon and selecting Inspect Popup and clicking the console tab in the top right.

You can access the background console by going to chrome://extensions and selecting Background Page which is to the right of Inspect views by your extension.

Make sure you're in developer mode. If you're not sure how to enter that, check out https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/getstarted

Comment: And in case of context scripts, the output will be in the page's console.